# FTP not showing files or directories

Tags: centos, iptables, ftp

I'm able to log into FTP but I'm not seeing any files or folders.

My iptables looks like this

-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport ftp-data -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport ftp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp-data -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp -j ACCEPT

When I ftp to localhost from the server itself, I'm getting the following error:

230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> debug
Debugging on (debug=1).
ftp> ls
**ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied**

---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,221,184)
---> LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>

Switching from passive to active gives me the same error:

ftp> passive
Passive mode off.
ftp> ls
**ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied**

---> PORT 127,0,0,1,233,166
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>

---

Passive mode shouldn't work because I haven't opened or specified a port-ranage, but active mode should work with these settings right?

**Update 1**

Config file VSFTPD:

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
listen=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO

Another note: I log in with my own user to /home/user and can't see any folders. But when I cd to / the folders are displayed without error messages.

Comment: It's not an IPTables issue if you're getting that much data back and forth - it's a folder permissions issue.

Comment: Please post your configuration file.

Comment: Config file posted and note added

Comment: I suggest you enable log on FTP server to see what it says. Did you try with other FTP clients?

Comment: Since I'm having the problem when I ftp from the command line on the server itself, I doubt that this is a client issue...What do you mean by "Enable log on FTP server"? VSFTPD logging is enabled and is not showing any errors.

Comment: Could be SELinux interfering. Try typing `setenforce 0` to disable and see if it works then?

Comment: That fixed it! (not sure how I should mark this is solved since Xhantar posted it in a comment....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, disabling SELinux seems to have solved the problem. I would suggest to now:

1. Turn it back on with `setenforce 1`.
2. Use `ls -Z /path/to/ftp/home/folder` to check the context of the directory you're trying to FTP into, and see if the context is "public_content_t"
3. If not, use [restorecon(8)](http://linuxmanpages.com/man8/restorecon.8.php) to fix incorrect context, e.g. `restorecon
   -R /path/to/ftp/home/folder`

Comment: the context is indeed not set to `public_content_t`, however step 3 doesn't change that. I'll read up on restorecon and report back.

Comment: Also look at the [chcon(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) and [setsebool(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setsebool) commands. It might be as simple as doing `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1` (allow users access to their home directories in SELinux). Note that it might take a while for changes made using `setsebool` to take effect while pending changes are written to the policy file on disk (a minute or so).

Comment: Have a look at http://beginlinux.com/blog/2008/11/vsftpd-and-selinux-on-centos/